# The Z-Index is not working with the radio button

Tags: html, css

Basically, the radio button is not working when I apply the z-index, but it does work when I remove the z-index.Any suggestions?

Here is the link to the code:

```css
  #firstqu {
  position: relative;
  left: 320px;
  background-color: #EAEDED;
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  z-index: -1;
}

header {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: purple;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
```

```html
<header>Test</header>
<div id="firstqu">
  <h1 style="color:black; font-size:25px;">1.Which superpower would you love to have?</h1>


  <p for="outdoor" style="float:right; margin-top:55px; width:200px; position:relative; left:0;"><input name="indoor-outdoor" type="radio" value="outdoor">B.Invisibility</p><br></br>


  <p for="outdoor"><input style="margin:0px; position:relative; right:0px;" type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor" value="outdoor">A.The ability to fly</p><br></br>

  <p for="outdoor" style="float:right; width:200px; position:relative; left:0;"><input name="indoor-outdoor" type="radio" value="outdoor">D.Super strength </p>

  <p for="outdoor"><input style="margin:0px; position:relative; right:0px;" type="radio" name="indoor-outdoor" value="outdoor">C.X-ray vision</p><br></br>

</div>
```

Comment: Why use the z-index? You move the element under the p element.

Comment: It's not very clear why you are using float, z-index, etc. Why not use css flex, for example? Also, why are you using a negative z-index and expecting it to help?

Comment: You'r simply removing the element's accessibility by applying a negative z-index.

Comment: Then how are else was it suppose to go under the header

Answer (score 1):

If you highlight the body from dev tools of your browser, you'll see the problem:

[image: Body over radiobuttons]

The body is over your radiobuttons. Giving more z-index to your controls, you can select them.

Comment: How do I make it work then

Comment: Simply remove z-index style in #firstqu :)

Comment: If I do that then, the questions will go over the header

Comment: Set z-index:1 in the header